# Show the available image in Node.js(when traffic limit exceeded)

Tags: node.js, http, server

I have an image hosting server that has a traffic limit 600M each day.

And I can also link the image with Google Drive. When I link the image with Google Drive, it's slow but there is no traffic limit.

So I want to let node.js server return the URL of the available image.

My image hosting domain is `image.com` and my node.js server's domain is `node.com`.

I'll insert image in HTML like this.

```
<img src = "http://node.js/image">
```

and node.js server's code is like below.

```
app.all('/image', function (req, res) {
  if(// should check whether 'http://image.com/' is available now' //)
    res.redirect('http://image.com/image.png');
  else      // The case that image.com is not available
    res.redirect('http://googledrive/imagesourceURL');
});
```

So how can I know that image.com is available now?

If I check it by requesting the real image file, it will use traffic of image hosting server so I think it's not a good idea.

What should I insert in **if(// should check whether 'http://image.com/' is available now' //)**?

Do you have any idea about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to check if a http resourse i available you should do a http ajax request.
In your case you should redirect to that URL if the status is 200 and to the other URL otherwise.
It would be something like:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: 'http://image.com/image.png',
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    console.log(textStatus + ": " + jqXHR.status);
        res.redirect('http://image.com/image.png');

  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    console.log(textStatus + ": " + jqXHR.status + " " + errorThrown);
    res.redirect('http://googledrive/imagesourceURL');

  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for youer Answer Panciz. I'll try it.

Comment: Pay attention, the code is asyncronous, your method will not block and wait the get response.